# Unit Testing Sitecore Installation from Different Server

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, sitecore

So, I'm new to Sitecore and not exactly sure how to enable this. I have a Sitecore installation on Server A and I'm running unit tests from Server B.  However, I'm running into issues accessing Sitecore remotely via their API (in the Sitecore.Kernel.dll).

1. The Sitecore installation has been setup correctly, I can access the CMS admin, I can add items, I can see the database, etc.
2. From the stack trace below, I can see that it's looking for the data folder (which doesn't exist on Server B, it's part of the Sitecore install on Server A).
3. Licenses are stored in this directory (the data folder) and since the calling code that is failing is called the LicenseManager I'm guessing that something is attempting to validate the license.
4. I've setup my unit tests as specified in the reference link below.  That has all the specific details of my setup (but feel free to ask questions).

**Question:** Is there a way to set this up to execute unit tests against a Sitecore installation from a different server (ideally through the Sitecore API in the dll)?

References:

- http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=232 - general setup
- http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/content_api_cookbook-a4.pdf - content api ref

Example Test Code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetItemTest()
    {
        var database = global::Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        Assert.IsNotNull(database);

        var item = database.GetItem("/sitecore/content");
        Assert.IsNotNull(item);
        Assert.AreEqual("content", item.Name);
    }
```

Exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The type initializer for 'Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager' threw an exception.
  Source=Sitecore.Kernel
  TypeName=Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager
  StackTrace:
       at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager.DemandRuntime(Boolean acceptExpress)
       at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.get_Provider()
       at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
       at Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem(String path)
       at Spacely.Web.Tests.Services.SitecoreServiceTest.GetItemTest() in C:\Users\foo\src\spacely\Spacely.Web.Tests\Services\SitecoreServiceTest.cs:line 25
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, RuntimeType declaringType)
            at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType declaringType)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
            at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
            at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
            at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(String assembly, String className, Object[] parameters)
            at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(String typeName, Object[] parameters)
            at Sitecore.Reflection.Nexus.GetApi[T](String typeName, T& api)
            at Sitecore.Reflection.Nexus.get_LicenseApi()
            at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager.GetSnapshotData(Guid instance)
            at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager.UpdateSnapshot()
            at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager..cctor()
       InnerException: System.ArgumentException
            Message=The directory name \data is invalid.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_Path(String value)
                 at Sitecore.IO.FileWatcher.InitializeWatcher(String filter, String folder)
                 at Sitecore.IO.FileWatcher..ctor(String folder, String filter)
                 at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseWatcher..ctor()
                 at Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.()
                 at Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi..ctor()
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The architecture you describe isn't possible, since the Sitecore API can't call "to another server," at least not in the way you are doing it here. The article you link to describes how you can set up a unit test project that runs independently of the web server with Sitecore. i.e. it would actually run Sitecore outside of a web context. This is possible, but can take a bit of work. Part of the required setup is placing the sitecore license on the server running the unit test, and pointing the dataFolder in the App.config to that location.

An alternative is to [use a web harness to run your unit tests](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/NUnit_Web_Test_Runner.aspx), but this is probably not the automated solution you are looking for. This solution is also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jorgelusar/sctestrunner). One idea we've had for some time is to call the remote test harness via web service. This would be one way to accomplish your goal of running tests from a remote server.

Comment: Part of what you mentioned worked for me!  The key steps were adding the data directory and a copy of the license in that file and deploying it to the correct test location (where the tests are actually executed).  Funny thing was, I actually had the answer on my desk the whole time... for anyone interested, check out John West's Professional Sitecore Development book.  My solution was in Chapter 8 - Automated Testing on page 338 - "Considering Calling Sitecore APIs Without an HTTP Context" (specifically, I missed steps 10 and 11).  Boo.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a few blog posts on Unit Testing, there are quiet old but still apply:

http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=232

Also look at Dan Solovey's blog:

http://www.dansolovay.com/search/label/TDD